# PayPal iOS Live App Settings - What is return url?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like to know what this is for (return url)? Is this some kind of deep linking to my app? I don't have any deep links to my app. I've been doing sandboxed paypal transactions in my iOS app, the user is just notified by a modal screen and then redirected to the home page of the iOS app.

Any tutorial about this or step to step guide for this? I need to go live today and I couldn't find a guide for this. thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple "return urls" for PayPal, it could be for the link the user is redirected to after a purchase (which the hint seems to indicate), or in this case for the "Log In with PayPal" feature (which the "Oauth return url is invalid" seems to indicate).

Quoting the [this doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/):

> You must specify all return URLs for an application in the Developer Dashboard before you can use that return URL in an application. For example, if you develop a REST application and you configure Log In with PayPal (LIPP), you must configure the return URL for the application in the Developer Dashboard for it to work in you LIPP configuration.

A starting point for more information on LIPP is: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/

Or, if you're looking for information on a specific API call:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/#tokenservice_createFromAuthorizationCode ... quoting that:

> Application return URL where the authorization code is sent. The specified `redirect_uri` must match the return URL registered for your app on the My Apps & Credentials page of the PayPal Developer site.

Comment: thanks. But before I accept this as an answer, I would like to confirm to you that in iOS app, the return url will not be used. Someone answered my question (this question) on the PayPal's Github Repo, and I guess he's right, I think the same, I can say this by my experience in having many transactions in sandbox mode.

Comment: @GlennVonPosadas May i have that github link please?